# Best way to display failed login from a nav login

Tags: navigation, css

I want to do a login for users that is strictly in the nav. If the user hasn't logged in, they can always login in from the nav. One thing I have noticed is that websites like Facebook and GoodReads go into a separate login page once they encounter a login error.

[image]

**The Remember Me and Forgot Password? is normally centered under their respective input fields. They are only off centered because of the Login error button. I can easily fix this...**

Please assume that there is no coding disadvantage, only focus on design. I can use AJAX to do the entire login process from the same page as the form. This keeps the user on the same page the entire page. What is the best way to display a login erorr from the nav of the login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to do a login for users that is strictly in the nav

In that case, better put the login form into a popover element (floating). You'll get more space for the form to layout it correctly. Your actual design is not so good by the way.

> What is the best way to display a login erorr from the nav of the login

If you use the popover way, you could show the error message under the form without affect the structure of the nav; in mobile this means a better experience. Other way to show a status message is using a toast. This messages are compacts absolute positioned elements, specially to show shorts messages, just like Codepen does.